# SBS 2011 Exchange 2010 Store.exe DB using 20GB with only 13 users?

Tags: exchange, memory

I have read up all the information there is about the store.exe (exchange db) utilising tonnes of memory, but I haven't found any reference guide as to how much of it is actually worth using per user.

My question is, is 20GB of store.exe db memory consumption too much for SBS 2011 Exchange 2010 with only 13 users?

Answer (score 2):

It's a normal behavior. Exchange allocate all memory and release it to the OS if another application need it.

> By default, the msExchESEParamCacheSizeMax key is not set, which means
>   the store can allocate the memory it needs dynamically. ESE
>   (store.exe) will grow the cache to consume almost all available RAM on
>   the server if there is no other memory pressure on the system For
>   example, if the server contains 16gb physical memory, if there is no
>   other memory pressure, one could expect that the store.exe process
>   will grow to use up to 14gb memory (16gb minus 2gb allocated to Kernel
>   mode). This much larger database cache size results in greatly reduced
>   disk I/O, and is preferred anyways, as reading information from memory
>   is much faster than reading information from disk. If memory pressure
>   occurs, as when other applications request/require memory, ESE will
>   appropriately shrink the size of the database cache. It’s not
>   recommended to modify the msExchESEParamCacheSizeMax attribute of the
>   information store object. Lowering this value may degrade performance,
>   in terms of server performance as well as in terms of end-user
>   experience.

from; http://blogs.technet.com/b/maliks/archive/2012/04/25/exchange-2010-store-exe-service-takes-high-memory-utilization.aspx

Comment: I understand that store.exe utilises a lot of memory, but is there a table to compare per user how much memory is actually required? Because I don't think that only 13 users will be accessing 20GB of cached db data at any one time.

Comment: Is that memory trying to be used by something else?  The memory manager is allocating ram exactly how it should- as cache until another process or memory request comes in.

Comment: @MickIlovski It's a normal behavior like stated. An example, in a lab I have with **no user** in exchange and store use all memory. There is no per-user ratio. Check the link I gave, you can force a max value but as we don't know the ratio it can hurt performance.

Comment: @MickIlovski and lets not forget that if an app ask memory, store.exe release some.